# Java and jtextfield value

Tags: java, button, jtextfield

I have `jTextFields`. If the user type tHe AET , the HOST and the PORT NUMBER in them, I need to save that permanently when he clicks on the save button.
How can I do that with Java to display the values automatically every time I run my application?

Comment: Either use a database or use file system to save the values.

Comment: store the value in file and when open app next time show th avalues

Comment: how could I use a file system to save the values

Comment: Please could you edit your question to add how you would like to persist the data. This would give a better indication on how the problem should be addressed

Comment: You just create a file and store the values in it

Comment: @JacquesRamsden OP doesn't have an  idea that how exactly data persistence  can be done.

Comment: Ok a better question would be... Are you trying to persist the data across devices or is it just for that user on that PC?

Comment: I'm trying to persist the data across devices

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

You could save to a **file**.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File('myFile.txt'));
pw.printLine(textField.getText());
```

to read from **file** would be....

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       // process the line.
    }
}
```

More information on **files** [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIO/article.html)

you could save to the users **registry**.

```
Preferences userPref = Preferences.userRoot();
userPref.put('textFieldKey', textField.getText());
```

to read from **registry** would be....

```
Preferences userPref = Preferences.userRoot();
userPref.get('textFieldKey', 'defaultValue');
```

More information on **preferences/registry storage** [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html)

You could also save to a **DB** but this would require **SQL** knowledge.

Example and tut [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

There is also the option of using **serialization** please see an example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html)

Comment: I saved the values to a property file, but I need to get those values automatically each time I run the application. How to do that?

Comment: Create a class called with a static method of that reads in the values from file. If the class property is null if it's not null then return them

Comment: I created a class called "public class savePacs" to get those values and set them to the jtextFields:           `aetPacs.setText(pacs.getProperty("aet"));
 hostPacs.setText(pacs.getProperty("host"));
 portPacs.setText(pacs.getProperty("port")); `                                              But how should I call it and in which part of my program?

Comment: Thats entirely up to how you have designed your application and its flow. You could call it when the view is created and all components are initialized. Then have the constructor of that view call a method called updateView(). in that method you can call out to the class that gets the values from the file and update each field accordingly.